# Why can't we black list questions with description contain mobile number and string loans?

Tags: discussion, spam

As we seeing lots of spam why can't we black list questions with description contain mobile number and string "loans" combo in this platform?

Comment: That should be discussed on https://meta.stackexchange.com/. It's a good question and could technically be simple and simply implemented.

Comment: Seems simple, just block Indian IP addresses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Massive Spam Attacks since couple of days](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9889/massive-spam-attacks-since-couple-of-days) I had an similar question

Comment: You can't ban things with the string "loans" because words like "loan" and "lease" (and "interest" and "amortize") are all used in technical contexts.

Comment: I doubt this is spam. It's more valuable as a vector for phishing/malware. If anything is being sold, it is the ability to get forum visitors to click on a potentially hostile link.

Answer (score 2):

To let it know the site can make such regex but via the smoke detector’s bot. (Which is no longer an option during the strike, as the bot is turned off)

In exemple before the moderator strike we asked on SF to make a regex for an event (WWE/UFC) that was spammed a lot. It worked as smoke detector was deleting faster those, and we asked to make it auto flag as spam such link way more heavily.

Sadly smoke detector is now at off for the time of the strike, and it’s to see if SE staff will try to implement such antispam feature before trying to simply talk to the moderators to resolve the issue, so we could start again smokey…

Sorry that the issue make the site experience go bad, but I can state that some staffs are now trying to clean the spam.

Comment: We have two ways. First don't let user submit the question which is more suitable i believe, other one is let the user feed the question and bot will delete it if found suspicious. So by this way we have two layers act as active, active. I am sure how it's implemented just sharing thoughts, team may be already thought of this.

Comment: @asktyagi The central theme is that [there's an strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/#). SE made some changes that angered a *lot* of the people moderating various sites, including the people running Smokey. Thus the situation. Most people believe the strike is a temporary state - and intend return to moderation once the issues are resolved.